# Can reaction powers by default be disabled as a free action?

Tags: reactions, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, free-action

The reaction modifier's description includes,

> The user can only prevent the reaction effect from occurring by choosing to deactivate the effect entirely (as a free action), in which case no circumstance will trigger it.

Is there another reference to this? Can all reaction powers be enabled / disabled via a free action by default?

Comment: Is there anything ValhallaGH or I could do to improve our answers?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find another reference to using a free action to disable reaction powers.

Using it as a general rule in the system is certainly fine. 
The other interpretation is that all naturally Reaction action abilities can be ignored (despite their triggers) when the character desires, but any effect with the *Reaction modifier* is automatically triggered unless the character takes a free action to turn it off (and then the power is completely off).

Both readings are supported by the text. The second makes default Reaction abilities slightly stronger, but not enough to be a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the phrasing used in the rules

> When the triggering circumstance occurs, the effect activates automatically, even if it is not the character’s turn. The user can only prevent the reaction effect from occurring by choosing to deactivate the effect entirely (as a free action), in which case no circumstance will trigger it. For the ability to choose to have some triggering circumstances activate the effect and some not, apply the Selective modifier as well.

It's clearly possible to choose to turn off the reaction power so as to have it not trigger. As a GM, I'd say that the chance to do that is on one's turn, as with most Free actions, and only by using a Hero Point to be able to use it out-of-turn (which is not something covered in the rules, but turning off your aura just before your orphan sidekick tries to pull Johnny Acid off of the battlefield seems heroic to me, so fits under altering the scene).

Where things get more ambiguous is when else the power might turn off. 3E eliminated the (admittedly slightly baroque) 2E system of having a duration to the Reaction power, which governed whether the power turned off when you couldn't devote a Free action to it (Sustained), stayed on even if Unconscious until you dismissed it (Continuous) or never turned off willingly (Permanent).

I would advise against making it too easy to ignore the Reaction, because it's a major factor in countering Reaction's ability to effectively give multiple attacks in the right scenarios. Even with Selective, that should just allow the user to modify the trigger, not decide on a case-by-case basis, as the trigger happens, whether to fire it off.